# SQL query to NHibernate query

Tags: nhibernate

I have a SQL query

```
select distinct e.ID, e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME, ef.PROJECT, r.NAME
from EMPLOYEE as e
inner join [RANK] as r on r.ID = e.[RANK]
inner join [EMPLOYEE_FUNCTION_IN_PROJECT] as ef on e.ID = ef.EMPLOYEE
where ef.PROJECT
in (
    select ef.PROJECT
    from [EMPLOYEE_FUNCTION_IN_PROJECT] as ef
    group by ef.PROJECT
    having COUNT(distinct ef.EMPLOYEE) >= 3
)
and ef.[FUNCTION] = 1
```

Now I would like to convert in to NHibernate query. This is what I've done so far

```
using (ITransaction myTransaction = mySession.BeginTransaction())
{
    EmployeeDAO empDaoAlias = null;
    Employee empAlias = null;
    Group groupAlias = null;
    Project projectAlias = null;
    Rank rankAlias = null;
    EmployeeFunctionInProject efpAlias = null;

    var subquery = QueryOver.Of<EmployeeFunctionInProject>(() => efpAlias)
                    .Select(Projections.GroupProperty(
                        Projections.Property<EmployeeFunctionInProject>(e => e.Project)))
                    .Where(Restrictions.Gt(Projections.Count<EmployeeFunctionInProject>(e => e.Employee), 3));

    empList = mySession.QueryOver<Employee>(() => empAlias)
        .Inner.JoinAlias(() => empAlias.Rank, () => rankAlias)
            //.Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<Rank>(r => r.Id), 1)) //indicate this is group leader
        .WithSubquery
            .WhereProperty(() => empAlias.Id)
            .In(subquery)
        .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property(() => empAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => empDaoAlias.Id))
        .Add(Projections.Property(() => empAlias.FirstName).WithAlias(() => empDaoAlias.FirstName))
        .Add(Projections.Property(() => empAlias.LastName).WithAlias(() => empDaoAlias.LastName))
        .Add(Projections.Property(() => ??).WithAlias(() => empDaoAlias.Project))
        .Add(Projections.Property(() => rankAlias.Name).WithAlias(() => empDaoAlias.Rank)))
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<EmployeeDAO>())
        .List<EmployeeDAO>().ToList();
}
```

First off, I need to modify

```
.Add(Projections.Property(() => ??).WithAlias(() => empDaoAlias.Project))
```

to show Project ID

Secondly, the query doesn't seem to work correctly, can anyone help me to correct this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you trying to project to a class instance (`empDaoAlias.Project`)? If so, this won't work in QueryOver.

Answer (score 0):

**What you wan't to achieve is easier:**

- if you use NH 3.3.x.x and IQueryable's
- or if you break your select into 2 parts

**But let's try to address problem in an other way:** if you do not plan to change the underlying DB, use EF for querying/reporting. **CQRS** is a commonly implemented pattern. The suggested use of EF for querying (NH for updates) is quiet common in the project's we've realized for the last 4-6 yrs.